# JavaScript dont listening to bool updated value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Followed by the code the `(bool) flag` variable should be false when a new input append to the .block element which should stop appending multiple input items.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hasantg/ja0he104/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a.action').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this  = $(this),
            type  = $this.data('type'),
            $block = $this.closest('div.block');
        if (type == 'newform') {
            var $form = $('<div class="form"><input type="text" /></div>'),
                flag = true;
            if (flag == true) {
                $block.append($form);
                flag = false;
            }
            // flag = false;
        }
    });

});
```

I cant understand what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Your `flag` variable is *redeclared* (to `true`) every time this click event is ran.  This is happening because you are doing `var flag = true;` *inside* the function.  You need to do `var flag = true;` *outside* the function.

Comment: @RocketHazmat thanks man, that was simple ..

Comment: another approach https://jsfiddle.net/ja0he104/8/

Comment: @Sushil yes! that was smart, i liked this approach

Comment: sure @meh-_-. posting my answer now. give me a couple of minutes

Comment: posted my answer @meh-_-. please accept it and upvote it if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a `flag` for each of your elements. you can go with @TbWill4321's approach or you can try this approach.

what you can do is add a `data` attribute to each of your elements. let's say the name of the data attribute is **added** which means if an input is added to the element or not.

in the `click` event you can check if the flag exists and add it if it does not

```
if (typeof $this.data('added') == 'undefined') {
    $this.data('added', false);
}
```

then check the value of the flag in your `if` condition like this

```
if (type == 'newform') {
    var $form = $('<div class="form"><input type="text" /></div>');
    var flag = $this.data('added');

    if (flag == false) {
        $block.append($form);
        $this.data('added', true);
    }
}
```

here's a working **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ja0he104/8/)** for the same. hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.action').each(function() {
        var flag = true;
        $(this).on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var $this  = $(this),
                type  = $this.data('type'),
                $block = $this.closest('div.block');
            if (type == 'newform' && flag) {
                var $form = $('<div class="form"><input type="text" /></div>');
                $block.append($form);
                flag = false;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Edit: Performance update, only creates `$form` if needed.

Edit: Looped over each action selector and created flag for each.

Comment: try opening the fiddle and update this code. he has multiple rows and this will only work for either 1 of the rows

Comment: @Sushil: Ah.  Good point.  Looks like he needs a `flag` for *each* element.

Comment: @RocketHazmat did u try it on all the rows?? it lets u append the input on 1 row and does not let u append it on other rows

Comment: Please make sure to put the reason something won't work, rather than just stating it won't work.  If I hadn't updated the answer or anybody commented back, it would have confused searchers.

Comment: I was adding another comment before @RocketHazmat commented